# How to put multiple outputs into one program

Tags: java

So my assignment was to figure out four outputs. For example:

```
public class Idk
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int i=1;
    while(i<6)
    {
      System.out.print(i + " ");
      System.out.print(i + " ");
      i+=1;
    }
    System.out.print("Out of loop");
  }
}
```

This code will produce 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 
But my question is that I have three more different outputs(sysouts) that I have to put into one java file, how would I do that? Or I should just add the other outputs(sysouts) and make one huge program?

Comment: What output do you expect exactly? 111112222233333.... like this? And please try to follow coding standards

Comment: `sysouts` means what exactly? Output streams? What kind of output and where are you looking to deliver it?

Comment: You should add those and make a larger project yes. Would be lovely if I were done with my programs when I reached 14 lines of code. Everything that directly has to do with your application should be in your application.

Comment: Please try to describe the problem better (Should be clear,crisp and non-ambigous). Else folks here will have to spend more time trying to understand the question than actually solving it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print 1122334455 three times, then just put it in another loop

```
for(int k = 0 ; k < 3 ; k++) {
       while(i<6) { 
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                System.out.print(i + " "); 
                i+=1;
       }
```

}

**Please learn the basics before asking **